# Making my own npm pacakage, keep getting TypeScript Error

Tags: node.js, npm

So im trying to make my first npm package, and so far its not going well...

```
const request = require('request');

module.exports = function get(username) {
if (typeof username !== "string") throw new TypeError("Please input a 
username after the function");
var rap = 0;
request('https://pa.developer-variety.com/api/AccountRap.php?username=' + 
username, (err, response, body) => {
  var obj = JSON.parse(body[0]);
  rap = obj.rap;
});
return rap; //What it comes back with
};
```

and when trying to use this package, it returns with this:

```
const rblx = require("rorap-js");

rblx.get("username");
```

Error:

```
rblx.get("username");
 ^
TypeError: rblx.get is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of exporting is not correct. The correct way would be:

```
module.exports.get = function(username){ .... }
```

Apart from this your return statement won't send exact response. You need to use either promises or callbacks here.